# BadRequest when getting presigned object with token and credential values changing

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, webclient

I have a presigned S3 URL that returns a JSON file. I need to use this URL in my Spring Boot application to retrieve the file, so I'm using `WebClient`.

Here is my code:

```java
@RestController
public class Demo {

    private final WebClient client;

    @Autowired
    public Demo(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.client = webClientBuilder
                .baseUrl("https://<base_url>.s3.amazonaws.com")
                .build();
    }

    @GetMapping("/data")
    public String processS3URL() {

        return client.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/<urlPath>.json")
                        .queryParam("X-Amz-Security-Token", <securityToken>)
                        .queryParam("X-Amz-Algorithm", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256")
                        .queryParam("X-Amz-Date", "20230913T103914Z")
                        .queryParam("X-Amz-SignedHeaders", "host")
                        .queryParam("X-Amz-Expires", "172800")
                        .queryParam("X-Amz-Credential", <credential>)
                        .queryParam("X-Amz-Signature", <signature>)
                        .build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
    }
}
```

However, I'm encountering an issue:

> java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from GET {givenURL}

Upon careful inspection, I noticed that the token and credential values have been altered by WebClient. Specifically, the token and credential values in the error URL differ from the original values I provided.

For instance, a segment of the token in the URL, returned by the error, appears as "HYVG6%252F202309" instead of the original "HYVG6%2F202309". The same issue occurs with the signature.

Why is this happening? How can I retrieve the expected result using WebClient?

Alternatively, are there other methods to retrieve data from a presigned URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any other ways to retrieve the data from presigned URL

**Yes, you should ideally be using the AWS SDK for Java to get presigned objects - and as much as possible for any other interaction with AWS** - as the SDK handles all of the low-level detail for you.

There's an AWS provided example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html#get-presignedobject) of how to do so.

However, if for some reason the SDK is not an option, or if you’re just curious to understand the issue, the remainder of this answer addresses that.

> For instance, a segment of the token in the URL, returned by the error, appears as "HYVG6%252F202309" instead of the original "HYVG6%2F202309".

**Your token and credential values are being double encoded.**

Using the example you've provided, your token has already been URL encoded - `HYVG6%2F202309`. The presence of `%2F` proves this, as in ASCII, the `/` character is represented as `2F` in hex. Encoding `HYVG6/202309` will result in the above value, with `/` being encoded as `%2F`.

The error throws `HYVG6%252F202309` as the token value. When you see “%252F”, it means that your “%” character is being encoded *again*. In ASCII, the `%` character is represented as `25` in hex. So `%2F` becomes `%252F` after the second round of encoding. Encoding `HYVG6%2F202309` will result in the above value, with the `%` being encoded as `%25`.

An easy way to fix this would be to first decode the values before passing them to the `uriBuilder`. This way, when the `uriBuilder` does its encoding, it will return your values to their original form.

Or alternatively, you can also change the encoding mode of the `WebClient` by creating a [`DefaultUriBuilderFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/DefaultUriBuilderFactory.html) with the [`EncodingMode`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.html) set to [`NONE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.html#NONE) & setting it as the desired factory for the [`WebClient.Builder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.Builder.html).

As per [the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/DefaultUriBuilderFactory.java#L47), the default encoding mode is `TEMPLATE_AND_VALUES` which encodes the URI template as well as the template values (your token and credential values).

`EncodingMode.NONE` will result in no encoding being applied, and the request being sent successfully.

This should work:

```java
@Autowired
public Demo(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
    factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);

    this.client = webClientBuilder
        .baseUrl("https://<base_url>.s3.amazonaws.com")
        .uriBuilderFactory(factory)
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Two things I would do to investigate -

1. Check the URI in your browser. Does it give you a response?
2. Where is the signature being generated?

All that said, you may just want to use the AWS SDK S3 library to generate the URL and invoke it directly instead of building it from scratch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html